# Generic type in generic collection

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have  generic type that looks like:

```
public class GenericClass<T, U> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // Class definition here
}
```

I then have a collection of these instances.  What is the cleanest way to pass through the type constraints?

```
public class GenericCollection<V> where V : GenericClass<T, U> // This won't compile
{
    private GenericClass<T, U>[] entries;

    public V this[index]
    {
        get{ return this.entries[index]; }
    }
}
```

Is there perhaps a better way to design this?  I think that specifying

```
GenericCollection<T, U, V> where V : GenericClass<T, U>
```

seems awkward.  Might be my only option though....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating a generic class, *all* generic type parameters of all objects used in all members of the generic class must be resolvable at compile time.

You can have type parameters that are *specific* instances of other generic types - for example:

```
public class GenericCollection<T> where T : GenericClass<int, string> { ... }
```

But if you want the type parameters of `GenericClass` to be generic themselves, then all of those types need to be part of the class declaration, as you've written:

```
GenericCollection<T, U, V> where V : GenericClass<T, U>
```

Sorry if it seems awkward, but that's your only option.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the field being declared, `private GenericClass<T, U>[] entries`, should probably be written as `private V[] entries`.  I don't think that the code will compile otherwise, the indexer property won't be valid without a cast.

Answer (score 2):

I think the collection will need the same constraints as GenericClass:

```
public class GenericCollection<T, U> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private GenericClass<T, U>[] entries;
}
```

Comment: I tried that at first but I wanted to have a type-safe indexer.  I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Brian Why can you not have public GenericClass<T, U> this[int index]?  How is that not type-safe?

Comment: You're right.  type-safe is probably not the right word.  I really want to avoid casting the GenericClass later if possible.  In retrospect this solution is also valid.  I probably should have stuck with my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is

```
public class GenericClass<T, U> where T : IComparable<T>
{
     // Class definition here
}

public class GenericCollection<T,U>  where T : IComparable<T>
{
     private GenericClass<T, U>[] entries;
     public GenericClass<T, U> this[int index]
      {
         get{ return this.entries[index]; }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you really want..

```
    class g<t, u> where t : IComparable<t>
{
}

class gc<t, u>
{
    private g<t, u>[] entries;

    public g<t, u> this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.entries[index]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't declared it as a class!

```
public class GenericCollection<V>
```