# Generic Type as a Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to use a generic type within another generic type.

but getting the following exception:

> The type `'MockManagers.ToPos'` cannot be used as type parameter `'Res'` in the generic type or method `'MockManagers.IMockManager<Req,Res>'`. 
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from `'MockManagers.ToPos'` to `'MockManagers.MockResponseObject<System.IComparable>'`.

I tried few option to solve this without any luck.
This [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560902/generic-type-in-generic-collection) suggest to pass the inner generic type to as a parameter to the higher level generic type. is this the only solution?

The code:
My Interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents IMockManager for mock object creation object.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="Req">The request object Type.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="Res">The response object type.</typeparam>
public interface IMockManager<Req, Res>
    where Req : MockRequestObject
    where Res : MockResponseObject<IComparable>
{...//interface definitions}
```

objects implementatation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents Mock response for a request object
/// </summary>
public class ToPos : MockResponseObject<byte[]>
{... //implementation}

public class MockBaseObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

 public class MockResponseObject<T> : MockBaseObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The response content.
    /// </summary>
    public T Content { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Res creation date.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `byte[]` definitely `IComparable`? I wouldn't have thought an array of them would be. If you remove that restriction for `Res` does it work?

Comment: have the same problem removing byte[] and using byte

Comment: Please examine the edit history - I went through marking up the code in the quoted area so that it actually made sense (because things that look like markup, such as `<Generic>` angle brackets become hidden). I'm not doing it again, but please do so yourself.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: No prob. sorry for that

Comment: eee... and which class inherit `IMockManager` ??  _roolyeye_ where interface is implemented ?

Comment: @Jasper You don't need to define a class to reproduce this: just declare a variable with the interface type e.g. `IMockManager<MockRequestObject, ToPos> foo = null;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you want generic variance on a class. C# only supports generic variance on interfaces.

Here's a simplified version of what you seem to want to work:

```
// Works fine: "string" is compatible with "IComparable"
IComparable a = new string('a', 5);

// Error: "List<string>" is not compatible with List<IComparable>"
List<IComparable> b = new List<string>();
```

This is only possible for interfaces, however, and then only if they satisfy certain variance constraints. One such interface is the `IEnumerable<out T>` interface:

```
// Works fine: IEnumerable is covariant
IEnumerable<IComparable> c = new List<string>();

// Similarly, IEnumerable<string> is compatible with IEnumerable<IComparable>:
IEnumerable<string> d = null;
IEnumerable<IComparable> e = d;
```

**So how do you fix this?** Here's one idea.

First, you can't use `byte[]` since it's not `IComparable`. Let's use `string` as an example, but you'll have to find something else suitable that implements this interface.

Second, make `MockResponseObject` an interface. Moreover, make it *covariant in `T`*:

```
public interface IMockResponseObject<out T>
{
    T Content { get; }
    DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

In order for this to work, `Content` *can't be settable through the interface*.

Last, update the rest of the code to use this interface:

```
interface IMockManager<Req, Res>
    where Req : MockRequestObject
    where Res : IMockResponseObject<IComparable>
{
}

public class ToPos : MockBaseObject, IMockResponseObject<string>
{
    public string Content
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Observe that `ToPos` still has a `Content` with a setter: you can set content as long as it isn't through the interface.

With all these changes, the following is now valid and compiles fine:

```
static IMockManager<MockRequestObject, ToPos> manager = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just declare `ToPos` as deriving from `MockResponseObject<IComparable>` instead of `MockResponseObject<byte[]>`, but then hide the `Content` property with a new one of type `byte[]`. However, for this to work you need something that wraps a `byte[]` and implements `IComparable`. For example:

```
public class ByteArrayComparable : IComparable
{
    public byte[] Data { get; private set; }
    public ByteArrayComparable(byte[] data) { Data = data; }

    // Implement IComparable.CompareTo() method here!
    public int CompareTo(object obj) { ... }
}

public class ToPos : MockResponseObject<IComparable>
{
    public new byte[] Content
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Content == null)
                return null;
            return ((ByteArrayComparable) base.Content).Data;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Content = value == null ? null : new ByteArrayComparable(value);
        }
    }
}
```